# Docker host rmi throws invalid authority but able to ping

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, alfresco

I've Alfresco, Running on one docker container A and exposes rmi on **say 33333**. Another normal java service runs on container B. Both are connected to same custom bridge network.

When container B tries to connects to alfresco via rmi using url `rmi://alfresco:33333` it throws `java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid authority: rmi://alfresco:33333/Abcdefghi`. But the same is able to `ping` alfresco. I think the url format given in rmi is wrong. if so. What should it be substituted with? I already tried `alfresco`,`alfresco.abc`. but same error persists.

Or else am I missing something in `docker-compose` file?

Here is the sample configuration of both compose files.

> **Alfresco (Container A):**

```
version: '3'
services:
    alfresco:
        image : xxxxxxx:latest
        container_name : alfresco
        expose: 
            - "33333"
        ports:
            - xxxx:xxxx
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test
```

> **Service (Container B):**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  abc:
    image: openjdk:8-jre-slim 
    working_dir: /home
    entrypoint: java -jar ABC.jar

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason. RMI is expecting either IP address or a valid domain. Since `alfresco` is available via service discovery and ping recogonises it, RMI assumes it to be an invalid URL. Hence I've to give an alias for alfresco host in a valid url format.

I gave an alias called `alfresco.local` now it works fine.

Here is my modified Compose file for alfresco:

> ***Alfresco (Container A)***

```
version: '3'
services:
    alfresco:
        image : xxxxxxx:latest
        container_name : alfresco
        networks:
        default:
            aliases:
                - alfresco.local #specify an alias in some valid DNS format
        expose: 
            - "33333"
        ports:
            - xxxx:xxxx
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: test
```